# A big problem: can not accept the alert when use selenium with python when from the first tab switch to the second tab that pop an alert when onload

Tags: python, html, selenium

## here is the python code.

1. open the second tab from click a button in the first tab
2. the second tab pop an alert dialog when onload, but the alert can't be found.

```
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('d:\\testalert\\testalert.html')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/input[2]').click()  # open the second tab

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # if don't switch to first handle, but directly switch to the second, code will dead.
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) # now current window handle is the second handle

time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
driver.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

## here is first html file(testalert.html) contents

there are tow buttons in the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display_alert_current_window()
    {
        alert("I am an alert box!!")
    }
    function display_alert_another_window()
    {
        window.open("testalert2.html")
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="display_alert_current_window()" value="Display alert box in current window" />
    <input type="button" onclick="display_alert_another_window()" value="Display alert box in another window" />
</body>
</html>
```

## here is the second html file(testalert2.html) contents

must be carefully the second tab will pop an alert when onload!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title2</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display_alert()
    {
        alert("I am an alert box!!")
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="display_alert();"> 

<input type="button" onclick="display_alert()" value="Display alert box" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: # here is the answer:
thanks https://www.cnpython.com/qa/1339790 again
```
driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[0])
driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[1])

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```
It can work correctly! After accept the primitive alert, other alert popup in the second tab can be found by switch_to.alert!

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> I have a new found! But what hell is it! It is too puzzled about switch_to.window and switch_to.alert!

This context is such as: python code with selenium open a new tab from first tab, the new tab popup an alert dialog as it load. For accept this alert, must switch to the new tab, because at this time the current_window_handle still point the first tab. So use the code

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])  # to the second tab
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()  # to accept the alert
```

but, the switch_to.alert will deadly wait, or print(driver.current_window_hanle) also deadly wait! Why is so? If don't use switch_to.alert or access current_window_handle, all thing is ok! We can use pynput.keyboard to simulate Enter key to accept the alert!

## here is the answer:

thanks https://www.cnpython.com/qa/1339790 again

```
driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[0])
driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[1])

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

It can work correctly! After accept the primitive alert, other alert popup in the second tab can be found by switch_to.alert!

Comment: The first part of this answer looks like it should be an edit to the question. Make sure that answers contain *only* an answer to the question.